# VM nodejs : Can VM module access nested dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am running a script in VM module by passing context to a vm instance as following

```
 var vm = require("vm")
 var file1 = require("file1")
 sandbox = {file1:file1}
 var code = " file1.saveInMongoDB({"que" : true})
 var script = vm.createScript(code);
 script.runInNewContext(sandbox,true);
  process.send ({"success"})
```

The dependency file1 has various other dependencies like mongodb library, file io etc.

The above script when called,should save the data in mongodb and exit by emiting a success event to master process. But, it never saves in DB

I executed the same script by using eval instead of vm and it works perfectly.

So, does it mean VM module cannot access internal dependencies ?

Comment: @codejammer, did you see the documentation? There is section explaining about the context, and the interpretation of this.[documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/vm.html)

Comment: @well : Thank you for the documentation. But my question is regarding the access of sandbox when it has internal dependencies. That part is not really well explained in the documentation unfortunately.

Comment: @vkurchatkin : I tried giving access to `require` but it didn't work.